# How to mock @injected object in class using Mockito?

Tags: java, mockito, junit5

I have the following Java code:

---

Filename: `MyClass.java`

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
...

public class MyClass {
  @inject
  private MyDatabaseDao myDatabaseDao;

  public MyResponse process() {
    ...
    String value = myPrivateMethod(x, y, z);
    ...
  }

  private String myPrivateMethod(String x, String y, String z) {
    value = myDatabaseDao.operation(x, y, x); // Line Number 86
    ...
  }  
}
```

---

Filename: `MyClassTest.java`

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class MyClassTest {
  @InjectMocks
  MyClass myClass;

  @Mock
  MyDatabaseDao myDatabaseDao;

  @Test
  void testProcess() {
    ...

    Mockito.when(myDatabaseDao.operation(any(), any(), any()))
                .thenReturn(someValue);
    ...
    assertEquals(testResponse, myClass.process());    
  }
}
```

I get a `nullPointerException` in line number 86 of `MyClass.java`, i.e., the `myDatabaseDao` object in that line is null. How can I properly mock and pass that object?

I am using JUnit 5 and Mockito v4.2.0

Comment: **The above code will work ideally.**

It didn't work in my case because I had some leftover code that was creating a new `MyClass` object (I had overlooked this while cleaning up code).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I belive it is because you forget to register `MockitoExtension`. To make `@Mock` and `@InjectMocks` to take effect , you have to register it :

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class MyClassTest {

  @InjectMocks
  MyClass myClass;

  @Mock
  MyDatabaseDao myDatabaseDao;

}
```

Comment: Oops, my bad, I have the annotation `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` in my code, but forgot to add it in the question above. 

I am getting NPE even with the annotation.

Comment: No idea . it should work. Or you try to add a constructor in `MyClass` which the input argument is `MyDatabaseDao`

Comment: Thanks for the help, yes the code works. I had some unwanted code leftover from a cleanup which I had overlooked and was causing the problems.